# Is there a way to draw a box like shape with only border using three js?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, three.js

I am a newbie to threejs, I wanted to render a box around a symbol in my canvas.The box should be transparent, should only have border around it .The border width of the box should be configurable.

Currently wireframe is used to render a box like shape and I am not able to increase the width of the wireframe to more than 1.It is also mentioned in the documentation that we cannot increase wireframeLinewidth more than 1.

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial

Current code implementation is as follow

```
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: feature.color,
  opacity: 0.75,
  transparent: true,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  wireframe: true,
  wireframeLinewidth: 1
});
```

Please help if there a way to build a transparent  box like shape with configurable border width in threejs

Answer (score 0):

> Please help if there a way to build a transparent box like shape with configurable border width in threejs

Rendering lines with WebGL line primitives will result in 1px wide lines. However, there is actually a way to create wireframes with configurable width. The following official example demonstrates this approach:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat_wireframe

The class `THREE.Wireframe` renders its line geometry as triangles (sometimes called wide, fat or mesh lines). Just import the class as well as `LineMaterial` and `WireframeGeometry2` and you can use this approach in your project.

`three.js R107`

Comment: Thanks Mugen, I will try this approach.